# Travel Companion Programs?

Tags: air-travel, travel-companions

I recently found out about these travel companion programs. Basically, they let you have someone flight with you for free. The second person usually needs to pay the taxes and surcharges.

My question is which travel companion programs are the best? Have anyone used them? Is it easy to find *eligible* flights?

The answer probably depends on which airlines I fly with. Any US airline would be good for me. Also, I'd like to know if there's a decent travel companion program that can get me middle east from the US.

Comment: I'm not familiar with such programs. Can you provide an example?

Comment: For example: https://creditcards.citi.com/credit-cards/citi-thankyou-premier-card/

Comment: Southwest, delta, virgin, ... have a similar program.

The conditions are different. Some just need annual fee of the CC. Some need earning huge amounts of points.

Answer (score 1):

The [American Express Platinum Card](http://transformtravel.americanexpress.com/Benefits/AllBenefits) has a international companion airfare benefit, however it requires you to purchase a business class or first class ticket.

Alaska Airlines also has a credit card featuring a coach companion airfare benefit: [Alaska Airlines Card](http://applyonlinenow.com/us/alaska-4cards/)

Comment: Note that the Amex Plat benefit generally only applies to full-fare tickets. If you don't mind fixing your dates, you can normally buy 2*non-flexible tickets for less than the price of 1*flexible + 1*companion taxes

Answer (score 0):

So far, I think [Citi Premier Card](https://creditcards.citi.com/credit-cards/citi-thankyou-premier-card/) is the best for US domestic flights (48 states excluding Hawaii and Alaska). To summarize:

- The annual fee is 125$ (first year's waived)
- You *can* get 25K bonus with eligible purchases (which covers you for 3 years of fees)
- You purchase any ticket/class and you get a companion ticket by just paying the fees (I think in the orders of 20-30$ at most, correct me if I'm wrong).